# Multiple nested consumers for React 16.3.0 Context API

Tags: reactjs

Following the new context API for react 16.3.0 I've created HOC so that my context is easier consumed by many components.

But if I have more then one component that consumes context nested one after another, react throws error.

Lets say for my example i have css module i want to pass down and HOC looks as follow:

```
import React from 'react';
import CssModuleContext from './CssModuleContext';

export default function withCssModule(Component) {
  return function CssModuleComponent(props) {
    return (
      <CssModuleContext.Consumer>
        {cx => <Component {...props} cssModule={cx} />}
      </CssModuleContext.Consumer>
    );
  };
}
```

Then I have two components that consumes this context:

```
@withCssModule
export default class A extends PureComponent {
  static B = B;

  static propTypes = {
    cssModule: PropTypes.func,
  };

  render() { ... }
}

@withCssModule
export default class B extends PureComponent {
  static propTypes = {
    cssModule: PropTypes.func,
  };

  render() { ... }
}
```

And the usage looks as follow:

```
render() {
  return(
    <A>
      <A.B />
    </A>
  );
}
```

> React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for
>   built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)
>   but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from
>   the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named
>   imports.

which throws an error, when I use only one of those components there is no error, but i can not nest them. Is this a common error? Is there a fix for it ? Or maybe am I doing something wrong ?

CssModuleContext.js

```
import React from 'react';

const defaultCssModule = null; // we want to use component defined module by default

const CssModuleContext = React.createContext(defaultCssModule);

export default CssModuleContext;
```

CssModuleProvider.js

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import CssModuleContext from './CssModuleContext';

export default class CssModuleProvider extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.element.isRequired,
    cssModule: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const { cssModule } = this.props;

    this.state = { cssModule };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <CssModuleContext.Provider value={this.state.cssModule}>
        {React.Children.only(this.props.children)}
      </CssModuleContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: What do the render methods of A and B look like ?

Comment: they return simple div, but it doesn't matter u can return null, and error still persist when u nest multiple consumers

Comment: Looks like you have multiple export default statements, or are those components in separate files?

Comment: different files, and they do work next to each other, error exist only when i nest them

Comment: @HunterMcMillen actually this is because i have declared B as a static property of A class, see updated question snippets

Comment: What you have shared looks fine, there is something else going on around that code that we can't see in the question.

Comment: Just to make sure, `A` and `B` are in separate files?

Comment: yes, they are, components A and B have to be fine, because it works without decorator, and with when they are alone, there has to be something wrong with context then

Comment: I have added more code snippets related to context, maybe this will help

Comment: The problem was because i was exporting HOC the static variables where not accessible on that object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was because i was exporting HOC the static variables where not accessible on that object.

doing the following

```
@withCssModule
export default class A extends PureComponent {
  static B = B;

  static propTypes = {
    cssModule: PropTypes.func,
  };

  render() { ... }
}
```

and then trying access the B like that `<A.B />` will not work because we export the wrapper not the class itself.